# Who was the first person to prove that only primes of the form $4k+1$ can evenly divide odd integers of the form $n^2+1$?

Tags: prime-numbers, quadratics, quadratic-forms, quadratic-residues

I am writing a paper and I want to cite the person(s) who proved that only primes of the form $4k+1$ can evenly divide odd integers of the form $n^2+1$.

Edit: added "odd"

For example, if $n=8$, then $n^2 + 1 = 65$. Both 5 and 13 evenly divide 65 and both are prime numbers of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: I suggest that you delete this question and post it [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I second José Carlos Santos's suggestion. I think page 103 of Davenport's *The Higher Arithmetic* (eighth edition 2008) might give the answer, but I won't post an answer here. Anyway, I should probably leave it to someone who knows!

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $n^2+1$ is even and divisible by the prime $2$ which is not of the form $4k+1$.